# Adapting a proof of the non-separability of Morrey Spaces for a different definition.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, separable-spaces

In the article ["Morrey spaces, their duals and preduals", by Marcel Rosenthal and Hans Triebel](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s13163-013-0145-z.pdf), for every $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $-\frac{n}{p} < r < 0$ the Morrey Spaces are defined as

$$ L^r_p(\mathbb R^n) := \left\{f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} \, \colon \, \| f \|_{L^r_p(\mathbb R^n)} < \infty \right\},  $$

where

$$ \| f \|_{L_p^r(\mathbb R^n)} := \sup_{J \in \mathbb N_0, \, M \in \mathbb Z^n} 2^{J(\frac{n}{p}+r)} \| f \|_{L^p(Q_{J,M})}, $$

where $Q_{J,M}$ represents the usual dyadic cubes in $\mathbb R^n$ with sides of length $2^{-J}$ parallel to the axes of coordinates and $2^{-J}M$ as the lower left corner. At some point (Proposition $3.7$) we have the result

> **Propostion.** Let $1 \leqslant  p < \infty$ and $-n/p < r < 0$. Then the space $L^r_p(\mathbb R^n)$ is non-separable.
>
> **Proof.** Let $$ Q_{J_l,M^l} = 2^{-J_l}M^l + 2^{-J_l}(0,1)^n, \quad l \in \mathbb N $$ be disjoint cubes with $Q_{J_l,M^l} \subset Q = (0,1)^n,$ where $J_l \in \mathbb N, J_1 < J_2 < \dots $ and $M^l \in \mathbb Z^n.$ Let
> $$ f^\lambda = \sum_{l=1}^\infty \lambda_{J_l,M^l}2^{-J_lr}\chi_{J_l,M^l}, $$
> where $\chi_{J_l,M^l}$ is the charateristic function of $Q_{J_l,M^l}$ and $\lambda = \{\lambda_{J_l,M^l} \}_{l=1}^\infty$ with either $\lambda_{J_l,M^l} = 1$ or $\lambda_{J_l,M^l} = -1$. Let $J \in \mathbb Z$ and $M \in \mathbb Z^n$. Then
> $$ 2^{J(\frac{n}{p}+r)} \int_{Q_{J,M}} |f^\lambda(x)|^p \, dx \leqslant \sum_{l \colon J_l \geqslant J} 2^{-(J_l-J)(\frac{n}{p}+r)p} + \sum_{l \colon J_l < J} 2^{(J-J_l)rp} < \infty $$
> where we used $\frac{n}{p}+r > 0$ and $r > 0$. Hence $f^\lambda \in L^r_p(\mathbb R^n)$. If $\lambda^1$ and $\lambda^2$ are two different admitted sequences then one has $\lambda^1_{J_l,M^l} = 1$ and $\lambda_{J_l,M^l} = -1$ for some $l \in \mathbb N$ and
> $$ \| f^{\lambda^1} - f^{\lambda^2} \|_{L^r_p(\mathbb R^n)} \geqslant 2^{J_l(\frac{n}{p}+r)} \left( \int_{Q_{J_l,M^l}} |(f^{\lambda^1} - f^{\lambda^2})(x)|^p \, dx \right)^{1/p} = 2. $$
> But the set of all these admitted functions $f^\lambda$ is non-countable, having the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. Thus it follows that $L^r_p(\mathbb R^n)$ is non-separable. $  \blacksquare$

I find the proof quite hard to understand, perhaps because I don't have much experience in dealing with the problem of separability of function spaces. Either way, the main purpose of my question is not the proof itself. Most of the time, when reading texts from different authors, Morrey spaces won't be defined in the same way. I am most used to the following definition:

Consider $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda < n$ arbitrarily. Then the Morrey Space $L^{p,\lambda}(\mathbb R^n)$ is defined as

$$ L^{p,\lambda} := \left\{ f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n) \, \colon \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \| f \|_{L^p(B(x,r)}^p < \infty \right\}. $$

**Now, my main goal is to prove that the Morrey Spaces (defined as I just showed) are non-separable for every $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda < n$. For this, I think that it might be possible to adapt the proof provided by Triebel and Rosenthal that I've quoted above, but I am having a hard time doing so.**

I appreciate any help, hints or answers in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I do want to comment on the usual way to show inseparability for a normed function space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$. So you need to find an uncountable subset $F\subset X$ in your space where any two points have a fixed distance from each other. That is, $\exists \epsilon_0>0$ such that $\forall f, f'\in F$, we have $\|f-f'\|\geq \epsilon_0$.

We now argue that any dense subset $Y\subset X$, that is, the closure $\bar Y=X$, must be uncountable. For consider the open balls $\{B(f, \epsilon_0/2)\,|\, f\in F\}$. By the fixed distance condition, these balls are disjoint. Now since $\bar Y=X$, $\exists y_f\in Y\cap B(f, \epsilon/2)$ by the characterization of closure. The $y_f$ are distinct (since the balls don't intersect), so $\{y_f\,|\,f\in F\}$ is uncountable. So is $Y$ by $\{y_f\,|\,f\in F\}\subset Y$.

The main way to find an uncountable set is by the power set $2^{\mathbb N}$, that is, the set of subsets of ${\mathbb N}$.

This happens for example for $\ell^{\infty}$. For any subset $I\subset {\mathbb N}$, define
$$
(e_I)_i=\begin{cases}
1 & i\in I\\
0 & i\notin I
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $\|e_I-e_{I'}\|_\infty = 1$ if $I\neq I'$. It also happens for your example of $L^r_p({\mathbb R}^n)$, where you pick any subset $I\subset {\mathbb N}$ and define
$$
\lambda^I_{J_l, M^l}=
\begin{cases}
1 & l\in I,\\
-1 & l\notin I.
\end{cases}
$$

---

Now we come to the other version of the Morrey space. The whole point is to establish a dictionary between the two spaces, so that we can translate the idea from one to the other. There is an unfortunate double use of the letters $r$ in the old and new spaces. I will have to settle to call the radius of a ball by $s$. This also happened for the $\pm 1$-valued function $\lambda$, and I will call it by $\kappa$ in the new version, and I will make it take on $1$ or $0$, since 2 is not so favored if we are not doing things dyadically.

So for $1\leq p<\infty$, and $0<\lambda <n$, define for $f\in L^p_{\text{loc}}({\mathbb R}^n)$,
$$
\|f\|_{L^{p, \lambda}({\mathbb R}^n)} = \sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}^n, s>0} s^{-\frac{\lambda}p} \|f\|_{L^p(B(x, s))}.
$$
(So we just take the $1/p$-th power in your definition to have homogeneity and get a norm.)

The idea is to draw the analogue between a dyadic cube $Q_{J, M}$ and a ball $B(x, s)$. So the lower left point $M\in {\mathbb Z}^n$ corresponds to the center $x\in {\mathbb R}^n$, and  the side-length $2^{-J}$ corresponds to the radius $s$.

If you compare the two norms $\|\cdot\|_{L^{r}_p}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p, \lambda}}$, you see we should have the correspondence
$$
2^{J(\frac{n}{p} + r)} = s^{-\frac{\lambda}{p}}.
$$
By $2^{-J}=s$, we get
$$
\frac{n}{p}+r=\frac{\lambda}{p}.
$$
This would totally match with the conditions of $-\frac{n}{p} < r < 0$ and $0<\lambda<n$.

Now let $\kappa:{\mathbb N}\to \{0, 1\}$. Let $s_l=2^{-l}\searrow 0$. Let $x_l\in {\mathbb R}^n$ **be chosen such that the distance $d(x_l, x_{l'})=\|x_l-x_{l'}\|\geq 2$.**
Then the balls $B(x_l, s_l)$ are disjoint. (We do need the sequence of radius to go down to 0 in an exponential fashion, and this is automatic in the dyadic version where we have $2^{-J_l}$ with $J_1<J_2<\dots$. **Also, we need to require the centers to be a fixed distance apart, which again is automatic in the dyadic version for the lattice points.**)

Let
$$
f^\kappa = \sum_{l=1}^\infty \kappa(l) s_l^{\frac{\lambda-n}{p}} \chi_l,
$$
where $\chi_l = \chi_{B(x_l, s_l)}$ is the characteristic function of the ball $B(x_l, s_l)$. (Again, this is borrowed from the dyadic version using our dictionary.)

Now we show two things. First, $f^\kappa\in L^{p, \lambda}({\mathbb R}^n)$, and second, two different such functions have a fixed distance apart.

Consider a general ball $B(x, s)$. Let $\alpha_n = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}$ denote the volume of the unit ball in ${\mathbb R}^n$.
Note first that since the balls $B(x_l,s_l)$ are disjoint, the different summands don't interact with each other, and we have
$$
|f^\kappa|^p = \sum_{l=1}^\infty |\kappa(l)|^p s_l^{\lambda-n}\chi_l.\tag{1}
$$

**We have to deal with two cases. First $s \geq\frac{1}{2}$, then $s\geq s_l=2^{-l}$ for $l\geq 1$.
We have
\begin{align*}
s^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x, s)} |f^\kappa|^p\,dx 
&= s^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,s)} \sum_{l=1}^\infty |\kappa(l)|^p s_l^{\lambda-n}\chi_l\,dx\\
&= s^{-\lambda} \sum_{l=1}^\infty \int_{B(x, s)} |\kappa(l)|^p s_l^{\lambda-n}\chi_l\,dx\\
&\leq s^{-\lambda} \sum_{l=1}^\infty  s_l^{\lambda-n} \mu(B(x, s)\cap B(x_l, s_l))\\
&\leq  s^{-\lambda}\sum_{l=1}^\infty s_l^{\lambda-n} \mu(B(x_l, s_l))  \\
&= s^{-\lambda}\sum_{l=1}^\infty s_l^{\lambda-n} \alpha_n s_l^{n}  \\
&\leq \alpha_n s^{-\lambda}\sum_{l=1}^\infty \big(2^{-\lambda}\big)^l \\
&= \alpha_n s^{-\lambda} \frac{2^{-\lambda}}{1-2^{-\lambda}}\\
&\leq \alpha_n \big(\frac 1 2\big)^{-\lambda} \frac{2^{-\lambda}}{1-2^{-\lambda}} = \frac{\alpha_n}{1-2^{-\lambda}},
\end{align*}
where the second equality uses the monotone convergence theorem, $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and at the end we have used that $s_l=2^{-l}$, $\lambda>0$, and $s\geq \frac 1 2$. Note that the final bound is independent of $s\geq \frac 1 2$.**

**Now if $s<\frac 1 2$, then since $d(x_l, x_{l'})\geq 2$, $s_l=2^{-l}$, we see that $B(x, s)$ can only intersect at most one $B(x_l, s_l)$. Let this particular one $l$ be fixed in the next equation. Then when integrating over $B(x,s)$, only the term for this particular $l$ in (1) is nonzero. We have
\begin{align}
s^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x, s)} |f^\kappa|^p\,dx 
&= s^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x, s)} |\kappa(l)|^p s_l^{\lambda-n}\chi_l\,dx\\
&\leq  s^{-\lambda}s_l^{\lambda-n}\mu(B(x, s)\cap B(x_l, s_l))\\
&\leq \begin{cases}
s^{-\lambda}s_l^{\lambda-n}\mu(B(x, s))=s^{-\lambda}s_l^{\lambda-n}\alpha_n s^n = \alpha_n\big(\frac{s}{s_l}\big)^{n-\lambda}\leq \alpha_n & \text{if }s\leq s_l\\
s^{-\lambda}s_l^{\lambda-n}\mu(B(x_l, s_l))=s^{-\lambda}s_l^{\lambda-n}\alpha_n s_l^n = \alpha_n\big(\frac{s_l}{s}\big)^{\lambda}< \alpha_n & \text{if }s_l<s,
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where we have used $0<\lambda<n$. Note that this bound for $s<\frac{1}{2}$ is also independent of $s.$
Therefore,
$$
\|f^\kappa\|^p_{L^{p,\lambda}({\mathbb R}^n)} = \sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}^n, s>0} s^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x, s)} |f^\kappa|^p\,dx \leq \alpha_n\max\Big(\frac{1}{1-2^{-\lambda}}, 1\Big) = \frac{\alpha_n}{1-2^{-\lambda}},
$$
so $f^\kappa\in L^{p,\lambda}({\mathbb R}^n)$.**

For a subset $I\subset {\mathbb N}$, define $\kappa^I:{\mathbb N}\to \{0,1\}$ by
$$
\kappa^I(l) = \begin{cases} 1 & l\in I,\\ 0 & l\notin I.\end{cases}
$$
Now let $I^1$ and $I^2$ be two distinct subsets of ${\mathbb N}$. Then there exists $l\in {\mathbb N}$ such that $|\kappa^{I^1}(l)-\kappa^{I^2}(l)|=1$. Then we have, by considering the ball $B(x_l, s_l)$ for this particular $l$,
\begin{align*}
\|f^{\kappa^{I^1}}-f^{\kappa^{I^2}}\|_{L^{p,\lambda}({\mathbb R}^n)} &\geq s_l^{-\frac{\lambda}{p}} \Big(\int_{B(x_l, s_l)} s_l^{\lambda-n}\,dx\Big)^\frac{1}{p}\\
&= s_l^{-\frac{\lambda}{p}} (s_l^{\lambda-n}\alpha_n s_l^n)^\frac{1}{p}\\
&= \alpha_n^{\frac{1}{p}}.
\end{align*}
Since the set of subsets $I\subset {\mathbb N}$ is uncountable, we have shown that this version of the Morrey space $L^{p, \lambda}({\mathbb R}^n)$ is not separable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and your time). I have some questions that you might be able to help me with. The first one is about the inequalities \begin{align*}
s^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x, s)} |f^\kappa|^p\,dx &\leq \alpha_n s^{-\lambda}\Big(\sum_{l:s_l\leq s} s_l^{\lambda-n} s_l^{n}  + \sum_{l:s<s_l} s_l^{\lambda-n} s^{n}\Big)\\
&\leq \alpha_n \Big(\sum_{l=1}^\infty \big(\frac{2^{-l}}s\big)^{\lambda} + \sum_{l:s<s_l} (\frac{s}{s_l})^{n-\lambda}\Big)\\
&<\infty.
\end{align*} You wrote that this comes from always using the smaller radius among $B(x,s)$ and $B(x_l,s_l).$ Can you give more details?

Comment: Yes, I have added more for this part. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks. There is still something I can't figure out about this first set of inequalities. How do you guarantee that the sum $\sum_{l \colon s < s_l} \left( \frac{s}{s_l} \right)^{n-\lambda}$ is finite? Moreover, why can't one apply this same logic to the first sum?

Comment: There are only finitely many $l$ such that $s_l > s$, since $s_l\to 0$. So this sum is a finite sum, and it is a finite number. (There is no infinite series here.) Of course, the first sum is a genuine infinite series, so you have to argue it is convergent. It turns out to be bounded by a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Thanks. With your explanation I was able to understand why the second sum is a finite one. I have two more questions, if that is okay: the first one is still about this set of inequalities: I still couldn't figure out why $\sum_{l=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2^{-l}}{s} \right)^\lambda$ is convergent. Your last comment about seeng it as a geometric series made me try to write $\left( \frac{2^{-l}}{s} \right)^\lambda$ as an expression with exponent $l$ (hopefully I would obtain a base strictly smaller than $1$...) but I was unable to reach this conclusion.

Comment: Second question is a confirmation about the second set of inequalities.To avoid confusion I will denote your element $l \in \mathbb N$ by $l_0$. In order to deduce your bound, I've used the following: for each $y \in B(x_0,l_0)$ we have that $$ |f^{\kappa^{I^1}}(y) - f^{\kappa^{I^2}}(y) |^p = |  \sum_{l=1}^\infty \kappa^{I^1}(l) s_l^{(\lambda - n)/p} \chi_l(y) - \sum_{l=1}^\infty \kappa^{I^2}(l)s_l^{(\lambda - n)/p} \chi_l(y) |^p = | \kappa^{I^1}(l_0) - \kappa^{I^2}(l_0) | s_{l_0}^{\lambda -n}. $$ If this is correct,then I've understood the second set of inequalities. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: For the first question, $\sum_{l=1}^\infty (\frac{2^{-l}}s)^\lambda = s^{-\lambda}\sum_{l=1}^\infty (2^{-\lambda})^l$, and $2^{-\lambda}<1$. For the second, what you wrote holds in this special ball $B(x_0, s_{l_0})$, and that is what we will restrict to. I will edit the answer also.

Comment: Just to be sure, yes, what you wrote for the second question is totally right. I didn't see your condition of $y\in B(x_0, s_{l_0})$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I have one further question about the first inequalities. Right now I understand everything that was done inequality-wise but there is one concern. With your clarifications, we've found constants $c > 0$ and $k > 0$ such that $$ s^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,s)} |f^{\kappa}(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \alpha_n(s^{-\lambda}c + ks^{n-\lambda}), $$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^n, s > 0$. This was done to prove that $f^\kappa \in L^{p,\lambda}$ but I think that the dependence on $s$ on the R.H.S. above doesn't allow us to conclude this. Taking the supremum on both sides we have

Comment: $$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, s > 0} s^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,s)} |f^{\kappa}(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \sup_{s > 0} \alpha_n(s^{-\lambda}c + ks^{n-\lambda})  $$ and I don't think the  right-hand side is necessarily finite. Perhaps I am missing something and you can enlighten me

Comment: This is a beautiful question. It did slip through me, because I don't think there was anything related in the dyadic version. I know how to fix it. Basically, what we did was for $s$ big, then there is a bound on this. For $s$ small, we can make the arrangement of the points $x_l$ so that it only intersects one ball. Then the technique for the second part of the proof will come into rescue. It will involve some substantial rewriting of the answer. I will get to it now. Thanks for spotting this point and make things correct.

Comment: Major overhaul. Question harder than I thought, but the result is better now, I believe. The revisions are in bold faces.

Comment: At one point you state "if $s < 1/2$, then since $d(x_l,x_{l'}) \geqslant 2, s_l = 2^{-l}$ we see that $B(x,s)$ can only intersect at most one $B(x_l,s_l)$." I don't think this is necessarily true: suppose that $B(x,s)$ intersects two distinct balls $B(x_{l_1},s_{l_1})$ and $B(x_{l_2},s_{l_2})$. Then one would have $$ \| x_{l_1} - x_{l_2} \| \leqslant \| x_{l_1} - x \| + \| x - x_{l_2} \| < 2^{-l_1} + 2s + 2^{-l_2} < 3, $$ which isn't enough to reach a contradiction with $d(x_l,x_{l'}) \geqslant 2$. Perhaps we need to assume initially that $d(x_l,x_{l'}) \geqslant 3$, what do you think?

Comment: Two extra questions I would like to make (which I think are the last ones): **1st QUESTION.** It seems like what we're doing in the proof is to build a set of functions $$ F := \left\{ f^{\kappa^I} \, \colon \, I \in  \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N) \right\} $$ such that two different functions from this set have a fixed distance apart and such that $F$ is uncountable. I can't understand how we guarantee that $F$ is uncountable. It suffices to find a bijection between $F$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ and I've thought about the function $$ J(I) = f^{\kappa^I}, \forall I \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N) $$

Comment: But I don't know how to guarantee that this function is injective. **2nd QUESTION.** Assuming that we deal with the first question, then our set $F$ is uncountable, such that wo different functions from $F$ have a fixed distance apart and such that $F \subset  L^{p,\lambda}$. Can you elaborate on why this suffices to guarantee that $L^{p,\lambda}$ is non-separable? By your initial text I believe this should be routine procedure in this kind of proofs but I would like to understand why. I finish by thanking you once again for all your help and the time you've dedicated to helping me.

Comment: About the distance question, our $l\geq 1$, so $2^{-l_1}+2s+2^{-l_2}<1/2 + 1 + 1/2=2$. So 2 would work already. About the 1st question, yes, we are thinking of such a bijection $J$. It is injective either by looking at the definition of the functions (two such would differ on a ball $B(x_l,s_l)$ of positive measure) or by the much stronger result we have obtained that they have a fixed distance apart. This is a metric space, so if the distance is positive, then they are different points.

Comment: I added the standard inseparability argument at the beginning of the answer. It was fun talking to you about this one.

Comment: Thank you. You've been very very helpful. All the best for you.